# Computing $n$-th external power of standard simplectic form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I need some help:

Define a 2-form on $R^n$ by $\omega=dx_1\wedge dx_2+dx_3\wedge dx_4+...+dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n}$. How to compute $\omega^n:=\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\ldots\wedge\omega$?

Comment: Do you mean on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? What have you done so far?

Comment: yes actually is called the standar symplectic form for $R^{2n}$    n=2, $\omega^2$=$2dx_1$∧$dx_{2}$∧$dx_{3}$∧$dx_{4}$

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
\omega=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{2k-1}\wedge x_{2k}
$$
so
$$
\omega^n=\sum\limits_{k_1=1}^n\ldots\sum\limits_{k_n=1}^n x_{2k_1-1}\wedge x_{2k_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge x_{2k_n-1}\wedge x_{2k_n}
$$
Summands here are non-zero iff $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ are all distinct numbers, so summands in bijective correspondence with permutations of numbers $1,\ldots, n$. Thus
$$
\omega^n=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}x_{2k_{\sigma(1)}-1}\wedge x_{2k_{\sigma(1)}}\ldots x_{2k_{\sigma(n)}-1}\wedge x_{2k_{\sigma(n)}}
$$
Since we are dealing with external product we may say that
$$
\begin{align}
\omega^n
&=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}(-1)^{2\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)}x_{1}\wedge x_{2}\ldots x_{2n-1}\wedge x_{2n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}x_{1}\wedge x_{2}\ldots x_{2n-1}\wedge x_{2n}\\
&=n!\; x_{1}\wedge x_{2}\ldots x_{2n-1}\wedge x_{2n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: what do you mean with $sgn(σ)$,  $sgn(σ)={1 if x>0, -1 if x<0, 0 if x=0$

Comment: this is [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation)