# Calculating power of wedge products

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

I am working on a problem and stuck at some point.

We have $\displaystyle \alpha = dx_1+ \sum_{i \geq 2}^n \xi_i \ dx_i$.

I would like to calculate $(d \alpha)^{n-1}$.

In other words, what is an alternative form of $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=2}^n d\xi_i \ \wedge \ dx_i\right)^{n-1}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be a $2n-2$ form, does your framework allow for such to be non-zero?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372776/computing-n-th-external-power-of-standard-simplectic-form

Comment: yes, actually I try to show that its nonzero on some field of hyperplanes but I don't know much about calculations on exterior product.

Comment: What manifold or vector space are you considering?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I solved with related question, thank you

Comment: @ArnaudMortier manifold is the projectivization of the cotangent bundle of X  P∗X = (T ∗X \ zero section)/ ∼